# Environment Variable for Personal Runtime Path? (~/.vim on *nix, ~/vimfiles on win32)

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to move my `.viminfo` file into my `.vim/` folder for cleaner syncing across multiple machines. (I have my `.vim` stored on Dropbox, and then create symlinks to it from my home directory.)

So this morning, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286925/4865822) on how to do just that. Great! Unfortunately, I use Windows at work and Mac at home, so `~/.vim` is actually sometimes `~/vimfiles`. As a result, a one-line solution

```
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
```

has now become a 5-line solution

```
if has('unix')
  set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
elseif has('win32')
  set viminfo+=n~/vimfiles/viminfo
endif
```

which just feels clumsy to me.

Is there some kind of default environment variable I can use to access the user-specific runtime path, à la `$VIMRUNTIME` or `$MYVIMRC`? Or is this something I just have to dance around?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work and is platform/plugin agnostic: `fnamemodify(expand("$MYVIMRC"), ":p:h")`

Comment: You people are geniuses.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you didn't change it, the first item in `&runtimepath` is your runtime directory by default:

```
$HOME/.vim        on unix-like systems
$HOME\vimfiles    on windows
```

You can use that value to tell Vim where to put your `viminfo` file with this platform-agnostic one liner:

```
let &viminfo .= ',n' . split(&rtp, ',')[0] . '/viminfo'
```

Resources:

```
:h :let-option
:h split()
:h runtimepath
```

Comment: Sadly this is not true.  `&runtimepath` is manipulated by plugin managers, there is absolutely no reason for it to start with `$HOME/.vim` or with `$HOME\vimfiles`.

Comment: @lcd047, in its default state, `&runtimepath` always start with the default user-level runtime directory for the current platform. Now, it is obviously possible for the user to butcher his `'rtp'` beyond recognition but AFAIK pathogen, vundle, plug, VAM and neobundle *all* leave `~/.vim` (or similar) at the beginning.

Comment: Only with the default configuration.  For a long time I used something like this: `pathogen#infect("$VIM/local/bundle/{}")`, to allow me to (1) have bundles available to all users, (2) keep them separate from Vim's main runtime, and (3) allow me to upgrade them automatically.  `~/.vim` ends up in the middle of the bunch with that setup.

Comment: @lcd047, I changed the wording of the first sentence as per our conversation.

Comment: Did it for me, and strikes me as the most elegant solution, given my setup. Thanks!!

Comment: Quick update: I ran into an issue where this line ran every time I sourced my `.vimrc` file. If I sourced `.vimrc` more than once per session (_e.g.,_ when tinkering with `.vimrc` and trying to test the results), `viminfo`'s location would be set to `C:\Users\Ryan\vimfiles\viminfo,nC:\Users\Ryan\vimfiles\viminfo`. To resolve this, I wrapped this line in the following if statement: `if &viminfo !~ ',n'` (which returns 0 if viminfo matches the string ',n').

Comment: Or, you can avoid re-reading the value by setting a global variable and checking that it exists (the same as plugins check to see if they're already loaded or not). E.g. https://github.com/mhinz/vim-randomtag/blob/master/autoload/randomtag.vim#L7, resp. https://github.com/mhinz/vim-randomtag/blob/master/autoload/randomtag.vim#L60

Answer (score 2):

First mistake I see time and again in relation to Windows is always attempting to solve the problem by using `$HOME`, don't.

Using `$HOME` will eventually cause problems, especially if you use any Unix-like environments (Cygwin, git bash, etc.). Don't use it in scripts, don't set it as an environment variable. In fact, setting `$HOME` will cause Cygwin to stop working correctly, and git bash to do similar. The more you play with `$HOME` the worse the bugs get, and tracing them down gets harder. Just don't use it.

Windows builds the `$HOME` on the fly and behind the scenes with `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. Simply use this inside your `_vimrc` or `vimrc` (without dot):

```
set viminfo+=n%HOMEDRIVE%/%HOMEPATH%/vimfiles/viminfo
```

This should solve the problem. If you changed `vimfiles` to `.vim` adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was rename Windows' viminfo folder to .vim (or copy the former's contents into the latter and then delete the former) and then symlink them with `mklink /d viminfo .vim`. (Note that mklink takes its arguments in the opposite order from Unix' ln command.)